# MySQL - Multiple values in a single row

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables :

TABLE Users :

```
id_user | name | job
--------|------|----
1       | John | Director
2       | Lila | Assistant
3       | Paul | Director
4       | Jude | Assistant
```

TABLE Site :

```
id_site | city 
--------|-------
110     | Paris 
111     | London
```

TABLE Contact :

```
id_user | id_site | is_assistant | is_director
--------|---------|--------------|------------
1       | 110     | NULL         | 1
2       | 110     | 1            | NULL
3       | 111     | NULL         | 1
4       | 111     | 1            | NULL
```

Let me explain. I have the different users of the company in the table Users ; the different locations of the company in the table Site and finally a table Contact that relates the table users with the table Sites.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT 
site.*,
`assistant`.`job` AS "Assistant Job",`assistant`.`name` AS "Assistant name", 
`directors`.`job` AS "Job director",`directors`.`name` AS "Director name"
FROM `site`
LEFT OUTER JOIN contact ON contact.id_site = site.id_site                   
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS assistant ON `contact`.`id_user` = `assistant`.`id_user` AND `contact`.`is_assistant` = "1"
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS directors ON `contact`.`id_user` = `directors`.`id_user` AND `contact`.`is_director` = "1"
ORDER BY site.id_site
```

The query is quite OK, but the problem is that I have results like :

```
id_site | city   | Assistant Job | Assistant name | Job director | Director name
--------|--------|---------------|----------------|--------------|-------------- 
110     | Paris  | NULL          | NULL           | Director     | John
110     | Paris  | Assistant     | Lila           | NULL         | NULL
111     | London | NULL          | NULL           | Director     | Paul
111     | London | Assistant     | Jude           | NULL         | NULL
```

I'd like to have all the information on the same row instead of having 2 almost identical rows. I'd like something like :

```
id_site | city   | Assistant Job | Assistant name | Job director | Director name
--------|--------|---------------|----------------|--------------|-------------- 
110     | Paris  | Assistant     | Lila           | Director     | John
111     | London | Assistant     | Jude           | Director     | Paul
```

I hope I'm being clear enough. Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much.

Stefey

Comment: looks like you need to PIVOT the results.. this question is asked before https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+pivot

Comment: Given that you have access to PHP, I think you're far better off resolving issues of data display there rather than in the SQL query, as was suggested by the answers to the 'duplicate question'. That said, there are lots of examples of this approach out there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the two `contact` IDs on the same line, it should work. The issue is that because it's joining to two rows, and joining to the split rows. So if you join the contact table twice (with a second clause for the `is_director` and `is_assistant`), you should only have 1 result for each. Then join to your respective `users` tables.

```
SELECT 
    site.*,
    `assistant`.`job` AS "Assistant Job",
    `assistant`.`name` AS "Assistant name", 
    `directors`.`job` AS "Job director",
    `directors`.`name` AS "Director name"
FROM 
    `site`
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    `contact` AS ContactAssistant
    ON ContactAssistant.id_site = site.id_site 
    AND ContactAssistant.is_assistant = "1"   -- Add this clause here
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    `contact` AS ContactDirector
    ON ContactDirector.id_site = site.id_site 
    AND ContactDirector.is_director = "1"     -- Add this clause here             
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    `users` AS assistant 
    ON ContactAssistant.`id_user` = `assistant`.`id_user` 
    -- AND `contact`.`is_assistant` = "1" -- No longer needed
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     `users` AS directors 
     ON ContactDirector.`id_user` = `directors`.`id_user` 
     -- AND `contact`.`is_director` = "1" -- No longer needed
ORDER BY site.id_site
```

Unrelated, are your `is_assistant` and `is_director` fields `(TINY)INT` or `VARCHAR`? I'm assuming they're numeric, so you may want to make sure you're treating them as such.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! I just adapted it to my query and that's working perfectly. is_assistant and is_director are BOOLEAN ! Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome! If it solved your problem, feel free to accept my answer :)